# CSV Data not Writing to Database, SuiteCRM, Custom Import Script

Tags: php, import, suitecrm

I'm writing a custom import script for SuiteCRM and I'm getting the error:

> Warning: array_combine() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean
>   given in /var/www/html/afscmedbv5test/custom/wimporter/newimporter.php
>   on line 162

My Script is as follows:

```
<?php
if (!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die ('Not a Valid Entry Point!');

$date = new DateTime();
echo '<H2>Wilderness Import Started</h2>';
echo $date->format('r').'<br>';
echo '----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
--------------------------------------------------------------<br>';

require_once("include/utils/sugar_file_utils.php");

WildernessImportJob();
die();

function var_dump_ret($mixed = null) {
ob_start();
var_dump($mixed);
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $content;
}

function time_elapsed()
{
static $first = null;
static $previous = null;
$now = microtime(true);
if ($first == null) $first = $now;
if ($previous != null)
echo '--- Partial ' . round(($now - $previous), 2) . ', Total ' . round(($now 
- $first), 2) . ' ---';  // 109s
$ret = round(($now - $previous), 2);
$previous = $now;
return $ret;
}
function myLog ($str2log)
{
file_put_contents('./zlog_'.date("j.n.Y").'.txt', date("H:i:s", time())." 
".$str2log.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
}
function calcDelta($a1, $a2)
{
//combine into a nice associative array:
$delta=Array();
foreach ($a1 as $key=>$value)
{
    if ($a1[$key] != $a2->$key)
    $delta[] = array($key => ("Was ". $a1[$key]. ", became " . $a2->$key));
}
$num = count($data);
if (empty($a1)) $delta[] = array("a1" => ("Was empty"));
if (empty($a2)) $delta[] = array("a2" => ("Was empty"));
return $delta;
}
require_once("include/utils/sugar_file_utils.php");


function fillPerson($record, &$person)
{

// $record is what is being imported from CSV
// $person is the bean about to be filled and going into the SuitCRM DB. It 
may be new or not, depending on whether it exists in the DB previously.
// name: only updates if not existant yet, because it's the key we use for 
search, and because names are more complex with parts


if ($person->full_name_c == "") {
    $recordname = $record["FULL NAME"]; // != "") ? $record["FULL NAME"] : " 
[To-be-filled]");
    //echo $prefix;
    $recordname = str_replace("  ", " ", $recordname);
    echo $recordname;
    $parts = explode(" ", $recordname);
    $person->last_name = array_pop($parts);
    $person->first_name = $parts[0];
    $person->name = $person->first_name . " " . $person->last_name;
    $person->full_name_c = $record["FULL NAME"]; // custom field created in 
    Studio
}
//$datanasc = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m/d/Y', $record["PPE"]);
//  $datasnasc->setTime(0, 0);

//  $person->ppe_date_c = ($datanasc == false) ? "" : $datanasc->format('m-d- 
Y');
//$person->ppe_date_c = $record["PPE"];
//print_r($person);
var_dump($person);
}

// finish by making a complete analysis of what changed:
return calcDelta($person->fetched_row, $person);


function GetOrCreateMember ($the_name)
{
//Check if the fullname is null
if ($the_name != "")
{
$person = BeanFactory::getBean("locte_Members");
$person = $person->retrieve_by_string_fields(array('full_name_c' => 
$the_name));
if (is_null($person))
{
  //get members bean
  $person = BeanFactory::newBean("locte_Members");
  //set full_name_c to the_name variable
  $person->full_name_c = $the_name;
//  $person->lcl_employee_id = $personEmployeeID;
  $person_name = str_replace("  ", " ", $the_name);
  $parts = explode(" ", $person_name);
  $person->last_name = array_pop($parts);
  $person->first_name = $parts[0];
  //combine first and last name to populate the fullname field
  $person->name = $person->first_name . " " . $person->last_name;
  $person_id = $person->save();
  // add new duespayment to member record
//  $rosterDuesPayments = BeanFactory::getBean('Dues Payments')- 
>retrieve_by_string_fields(array('name'=> $duesEmployeeID));
//  $person->load_relationship('locte_Members_adues_dues'); //confirm 
relationship name in cache
//  $person->dues_payments->add($rosterDuesPayments->id);
}
return $person;
}
return null;
}
function WildernessImportJob()
{
try
{
    time_elapsed();
    $GLOBALS['log']->info('Wilderness Import');
    $config = new Configurator();
    $config->loadConfig();
    $xmlDataDir =  'custom/wimporter/ToImport';      //$config->config['WildernessImporter_DataFilePath'];
    $GLOBALS['log']->info("Wilderness Import: Scanning XML Data dir $xmlDataDir...");
        echo("<h3>Wilderness Import: Scanning XML Data dir $xmlDataDir...<br /></h3>");
    $directoryContent = scandir($xmlDataDir);
    $GLOBALS['log']->info("Wilderness Import: Scanning XML Data dir $xmlDataDir... [Found " . count($directoryContent) . " files]");
        echo("<h3>Wilderness Import: Scanning XML Data dir $xmlDataDir... [Found " . count($directoryContent) . " files]</h3><br />");
      foreach ($directoryContent as $itemFile)
    {
          if (is_dir($xmlDataDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $itemFile)) continue;
          if (strcasecmp(substr($itemFile, -4), ".csv") != 0) continue;
          $GLOBALS['log']->info("Wilderness Import: Processing $itemFile file...");
          myLog("---------------------------------------------------");
          myLog("Wilderness Import: Processing $itemFile file...");
          myLog("----------------------------------------------------");
                echo("<h4>---------------------------------------------------------------</h4>");
                echo("<h4>Wilderness Import: Processing $itemFile file...</h4>");
          echo("<h4>---------------------------------------------------------------</h4>");
          $oFile = fopen($xmlDataDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $itemFile, 'r');
          if ($oFile !== FALSE)
      {
              // read entire file at once:
                  // expected separator is ",", expected encoding is UTF-8 without BOM (BOM is 3 weird characters in beginning of file)
                     while (($data[] = fgetcsv($oFile, 0, ',')) !== FALSE) { }
                                 echo('File opened..... <br /> <br />');
                        fclose($oFile);
                           //combine into a nice associative array:
                        $arow=Array();
                                        echo('Building CSV File Row Array <br /><br />');
                        $fields = array_shift($data);
                                        echo('Building CSV Header Fields Array as shown below:<strong> <br /><br />');
                                        echo implode(", ", $fields) . "</strong><br /><br />\n";


                          foreach ($data as $i=>$arow)

                    {
                    $GLOBALS['log']->info("Wilderness Import: array_combine " . $i);
                            $data[$i] = array_combine($fields, $arow);

                          }
                  unset($arow); // **********************************************! ! ! !! ! ! ! ! ! !! !


                  $num = count($data);
                                        echo('Build Full Array of Roster to be Imported Complete.  Entries to be imported are shown below <br /><br />');


                            for ($row=0; $row < $num - 1 ; $row++)
                            {   // normal bounds: from 0 to $num


                                  //$num is the number of lines including header in csv file
                                  echo "<strong>Filename: $itemFile   |   Roster Import, Row" . ($row + 1) . ":</strong><br />\n";
                                  $GLOBALS['log']->info("Wilderness Import: Importing " . $data[$row]["FULL NAME"]);
                                //  echo("<strong>Importing Roster Row #: ". ($row + 1) . "<br />" . "Local Number " . $data[$row]["AFFILIATE"] . "<br />" . "Employee: " . $data[$row]["FULL NAME"] . "</strong><br /><br />");

                                                echo "<strong><table>\n";
                                foreach ($fields as $field) {
                                //echo "<tr><td>" . $field . "</td><td>" . $data[$row][$field] . "</td><td>" . $data[$row+1][$field] . "</td><td>" . $data[$row+2][$field] . "</td></tr>\n";
                                }
                                echo "</table>\n";
                                                                echo "File Row Data:      ";
                                echo implode(", ", $data[$row]) . "</strong><br /><br />\n";


                                                                $Member = BeanFactory::getBean("locte_Members");
                                                                $FullName=$Member->full_name_c;
                                                              //$myfield_defs = $Member->getFieldDefinitions(); // just to help while developing
                                                                //foreach($myfield_defs as $def) echo $def["name"] . "<br />\n";


                              $Member=$Member->retrieve_by_string_fields(array('full_name_c' => $data[$row]["FULL NAME"]));



                                if (is_null($Member)) {
                                $Member = BeanFactory::newBean("locte_Members");
                                    $delta = fillPerson($data[$row], $Member, "");    //->full_name_c, "FULL NAME");
                        }
                                                    if (count($delta)) {
                                                        $Member_id = $Member->save();
                                    }
      }
              // Records have been saved: from this point on, only work on relationships:
        $GLOBALS['log']->info('End: Wilderness Import');
        myLog('End: Wilderness Import');
        time_elapsed();
        return true;
            }
        }
} catch (Exception $e)
{
    $GLOBALS['log']->fatal("Wilderness Import: Exception " . $e->getMessage());
    myLog("Wilderness Import: Exception " . $e->getMessage());
    echo '\n\nCaught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
  return false;
}
}
```

It does return info from both the database and the csv file.

Image of error below.

[Error - Capture from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67Icl.jpg)

Help always appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script is throwing error because the parameter `$arow` given to `array_combine` is not an array. So a check should be there to check whether `$arow` is an array or not.
Try code following:

```
foreach ($data as $i => $arow) {
    $GLOBALS['log']->info("Wilderness Import: array_combine " . $i);
    if (is_array($arow)) {
        $data[$i] = array_combine($fields, $arow);
    }
}
```

Read more about [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

**Update**

Code you are using to read csv need to be changed. Second parameter in  `fgetcsv` must be greater than the longest line (in characters) to be found in the CSV file. So replace code

```
while (($data[] = fgetcsv($oFile, 0, ', ')) !== FALSE) {

}
```

with

```
while (($data[] = fgetcsv($oFile, 10, ', ')) !== FALSE) {

}
```

Read more about [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Comment: That got rid of the error.  Script still not saving data to database..... Frustrating

Comment: Is there any code written to save data to database? Haven't seen in code added in question.

Comment: var_dump($arow); returning null.  Definitely shouldnt be as the data is being read from the file.

Comment: Code added is entire script so far, but should be complete for combining First and Last name and populating the field in the DB.  Not sure what I'm missing

Comment: I've seen code to retrieve data from csv. It looks good. Can you show format of csv?

Comment: right now its simply 3 headers..... FIRST NAME (db field = first_name), LAST NAME (db field = last_name), FULL NAME (db field = full_name_c)

Comment: LAST NAME,FIRST NAME,FULL NAME
BUTLER,BRIANA,BUTLER BRIANA                                                                   
  ^^CSV Format - New Line starts at Butler

Comment: @MicahYarborough Code Updated!

Comment: 0 is unlimited;  CSV file reads perfect already.  Data just doesn't save to database when the script runs.  It should using the save();  Last piece of the puzzle and I get stuck.  :(  I appreciate the help btw.  My brain hurts

Comment: Undefined variable: delta in /var/www/html/afscmedbv5test/custom/wimporter/newimporter.php on line 179     but it is defined right above  lol  its also a condition of save(); so thats prolly it but i have no clue why undefined

Comment: Error gone - $delta was in fact undefined as it wasnt null in the csv.  Still not saving to Database.  Running script returns $delta as Full Name properly, just doesnt insert the full name into the FULL NAME field in SuiteCRM.

Comment: Is there any data in `$data` variable?

Comment: $data[$row] dumps the csv array of headers with respective info.

Comment: The $Member variable is null........  Not sure why.  Probably something stupid, but I'm a .net guy.  Still learning PHP fully

Comment: MySQL error 1054: Unknown column 'full_name' in 'where clause'    changed full_name_c to full_name.  Both fields exist

Comment: Well it's all reading but still not inserting.  Should be a simple $Member->save();

Answer (score 0):

This block is doing the saving of records using the beanfactory....  I think :|

```
$Member = BeanFactory::getBean("locte_Members");
                                                                $FullName=$Member->full_name_c;
                                                              //$myfield_defs = $Member->getFieldDefinitions(); // just to help while developing
                                                                //foreach($myfield_defs as $def) echo $def["name"] . "<br />\n";
                              $Member=$Member->retrieve_by_string_fields(array('full_name_c' => $data[$row]["FULL NAME"]));
                                if (is_null($Member)) {
                                $Member = BeanFactory::newBean("locte_Members");
                                    $delta = fillPerson($data[$row], $Member->full_name_c, "FULL NAME");
                                                                var_dump($arow);
                        }
                                                    if (count($delta)) {
                                                        $Member_id = $Member->save();
                                    }
      }
              // Records have been saved: from this point on, only work on relationships:
```

Here's the output of the script in the browser with field definition dump

Wilderness Import Started

### Tue, 19 Jun 2018 02:05:56 -0400

Wilderness Import: Scanning XML Data dir custom/wimporter/ToImport...
Wilderness Import: Scanning XML Data dir custom/wimporter/ToImport... [Found 3 files]

---

### Wilderness Import: Processing L1554v4.csv file...

File opened.....

Building CSV File Row Array

Building CSV Header Fields Array as shown below:

LAST NAME, FIRST NAME, FULL NAME

Build Full Array of Roster to be Imported Complete. Entries to be imported are shown below

Filename: L1554v4.csv | Roster Import, Row1:
LAST NAME   BUTLER
FIRST NAME  BRIANA
FULL NAME   BUTLER BRIANA
File Row Data: BUTLER, BRIANA, BUTLER BRIANA

-id

-name

-date_entered

-date_modified

-modified_user_id

-modified_by_name

-created_by

-created_by_name

-description

-deleted

-securitygroup

-securitygroup_display

-created_by_link

-modified_user_link

-assigned_user_id

-assigned_user_name

-assigned_user_link

-additionalusers

-additionalusers_listview

-salutation

-first_name

-last_name

-full_name

-title

-photo

-department

-do_not_call

-phone_home

-email

-phone_mobile

-phone_work

-phone_other

-phone_fax

-email1

-email2

-invalid_email

-email_opt_out

-primary_address_street

-primary_address_street_2

-primary_address_street_3

-primary_address_city

-primary_address_state

-primary_address_postalcode

-primary_address_country

-alt_address_street

-alt_address_street_2

-alt_address_street_3

-alt_address_city

-alt_address_state

-alt_address_postalcode

-alt_address_country

-assistant

-assistant_phone

-email_addresses_primary

-email_addresses

-email_addresses_non_primary

-lcl_birthdate

-lcl_affiliate_number

-member_signature

-ssn

-staff_rep

-mem_join_date

-class_title

-steward

-olo_code

-enterprise_id

-member_card

-address_map

-member_status

-primary_language

-english_speaking

-annual_salary

-currency_id

-state_hire_date

-dues_frequency

-card_sent_date

-gender

-disabilities

-marital_status

-executive_board

-affiliate_type

-middle_name

-name_suffix

-mailableflag

-no_mailflag

-apt_number

-zip4

-infosrc

-lcl_phone_collected

-lcl_hasmobile

-lcl_hasemail

-lcl_member_status

-backofficeassistants

-backoffice_assistant_phonoe

-backoffice_assistant_email

-lcl_employercontact

-lcl_work_dept

-lcl_work_location

-lcl_jobclasstitle

-lcl_employee_id

-lcl_join_date

-lcl_sig_auth

-lcl_dues_status

-lcl_on_probation

-lcl_prob_end_date

-lcl_prob_term

-afs_signed_by

-afs_region_number

-afemp_employers_id_c

-afs_employer

-primary_address_county

-locte_members_adues_dues

-full_name_c

-locte_members_afcbu_cbu

-locte_members_afcbu_cbu_name

-locte_members_afcbu_cbuafcbu_cbu_idb

-ppe_date_c

--- Partial 0.01, Total 0.01 ---